# Download com HttpWebClient só funciona fora do Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma classe para download de arquivos em C#: [FileDownloader](https://github.com/LucasLor/FileDownloader). O problema está ocorrendo na utilização dela. Eu estou tentando fazer downloads simultâneos, ela está funcionando normal quando esta rodando fora do `Parallel` mas quando roda dentro dele  `using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync()) // line 205 da classe DownloadFile` fica aguardando para sempre ignorando o `TimeOut` e não faz o download.

```
    private async void DoDownload(string[] segments)
    {                   
        //Whether to stop downloading
        stopdownload = false;
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        //Multi-threaded setup
        ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2,
            CancellationToken = cts.Token
        };

        //Start Downloading
        OnDownloadStart?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        DownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.Downloading;


        var downloader1 = new Downloader.DownloadFile()
        {
            Url = @"https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/autobuild-2021-03-13-12-31/ffmpeg-n4.3.2-160-gfbb9368226-win64-gpl-4.3.zip",
            FilePath = Path.Combine(OutFolder.FullName, $"part_10.zip")
        };
        await downloader1.StartAsync();


        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(segments, parallelOptions,  async (info, loopstate, index) =>
                {
                    if (stopdownload)
                        loopstate.Stop();

                    var downloader2 = new Downloader.DownloadFile()
                    {
                        Url = @"https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/autobuild-2021-03-13-12-31/ffmpeg-n4.3.2-160-gfbb9368226-win64-gpl-4.3.zip",
                        FilePath = Path.Combine(OutFolder.FullName, $"part_{index}.zip")
                    };
                    await downloader2.StartAsync();

                });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            ;
        }
    }
```

O `downloader1` baixa normalmente enquanto o `downloader2` não. Eu fixei a url para uma que eu tinha certeza que estava funcionando. Mas por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 1):

O objetivo do `Parallel.ForEach` é paralelizar `Tasks` mas não com `async/await`, onde você espera devolver uma `Task` e esperar que ela seja completada.

O `Parallel.ForEach` deve funcionar bem com outro método síncrono do `WebClient`.

Para fazer `async`, tem uma abordagem muito mais simples que é usar o próprio `System.Linq` para criar `Tasks` e aguardar o resultado delas, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
// Para cada "segment" crio uma Task de download
var downloadsTasks = segments.Select(segment =>
{
    return new Downloader.DownloadFile
    {
          Url = segment,
          FilePath = Path.Combine(OutFolder.FullName, $"part_{segment}.zip")
    }.StartAsync();    
});

// Aguardo todos os downloads terminarem.
var downloads = await Task.WhenAll(downloadsTasks);
```

Supondo que "segments" tem os links de download ou pode montar o nome do download dentro do `.Select`.  Isso garante que vai devolver Tasks e vai fazer o `await` de todas em seguida.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu removi o `async` do código e voltou a fazer os downloads normalmente só que gerou outro problema. Tanto na sua implementação quanto na retirada do `async` as duas formas fazem o máximo de downloads possível, mas eu preciso ter o controle sobre quantos arquivos eu estou baixando por vez. Por exemplo alguns casos eu não vou poder passar de 2 e em outros de 4 downloads simultâneos.